# Error importing python swift client from notebook

Tags: ipython, openstack-swift

When I try to install python swiftclient and access it from a notebook, I receive an error:

```
!pip install --user python-swiftclient --upgrade

import swiftclient

>> Requirement already up-to-date: python-swiftclient in /Users/snowch/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>> ...
>> ImportError: No module named swiftclient
```

However, importing `swiftclient` works fine from a standard python prompt.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to make sure that `pip` belongs to the same interpreter as your `ipython` script.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is.  Did you get the above commands to work?

Comment: Fairly sure is not helpful :). Have you verified that `which ipython` and `which pip` point to the same interpreter?